# shared_ptr to lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, smart-pointers, weak-references

I have a class that registers lambda functions (as `std::function<void()>`) as callbacks for events it will generate. I'm using `shared_ptr` for memory management, and I need to be careful not to create reference cycles. I don't want the event vendor to own the callbacks, so it stores `std::weak_ptr<std::function<void()>>`.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make one of those! To make the owning `shared_ptr` instance, I need to pass in a pointer to an unowned, heap-allocated lambda. Is there a version of `new` for lambdas?

Comment: `std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>([]{ my lambda; });`?

Comment: Using smart pointers for `std::function` seems unnecessary and overly complicated. *Why* do you want to use `std::shared_ptr` for this? [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is copyable. And if you're worried about losing a reference to the original lambda function, then this won't help if the lambda object goes out of scope and is destructed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because the lambda may have captured a `shared_ptr` to another object, and I *don't* want to have a strong reference to it.

Comment: @Justin I may be wrong, but it looks like that instantiates a lambda on the stack and then passes its address to make_shared. Which would result in bad things (tm) when the shared_ptr went out of scope, or was dereferenced after the stack was cleared.

Comment: @ReidRankin You need to learn how lambdas work. A lambda `[captureList](args...) { body }` is basically syntactic sugar for `struct lambda { captureList; /* as members of the struct */ auto operator()(args...) const { body } };`. In other words, you can view a lambda as an object of a type along those lines. When you copy an object, it copies its members. There is no address being passed

Comment: @Justin There's no constructor for shared_ptr that takes anything but a pointer, so it must be getting coerced somehow.

Comment: @ReidRankin This isn't a constructor to `shared_ptr`, this is `std::make_shared`. Go read the [documentation on `std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). `std::make_shared` constructs the object on memory allocated from the heap, and passes the pointer to the allocated memory into `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Justin Good point. But it looks like it should be creating an object of type std::function<void()> and passing the lambda as an argument to its constructor?

Comment: @ReidRankin Yes, that's exactly what happens

Comment: @Justin Oh, wait, std:function has a default copy constructor! Duh. So that explains why it works.

Comment: @Justin Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ReidRankin The copy constructor isn't called; the object is constructed directly on the memory from the heap. Also, realize that this is approximately equivalent to `new std::function<void()>{ myLambda }`